# iPad : Problem with Orientation while dismissing the urban airships Rich Push notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, urbanairship.com

I have implemented UrbanAirships rich push notification in my app.

While I press the Done button(dismiss the urban-airship's view), my screen destructed as below.

[image]

What could be problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be with the Screenlocks that you might have or have not added in your XIBs . Also try applying stretch in horizontal and vertical mode in your XIB.

Comment: What is screenlock ? Is it auto sizing screen ?

Comment: Ya . If you have tried applying the auto sizing and positioning locks then you can try changing the contentmode of the image and if that does not work then try giving the frame of the uiimage through code.